# integral alternative of $\sum f(p)$ from $(1<\text{all primes}\leq n)$ to $(\text{maximum prime}<n)$

Tags: integration, prime-numbers, summation

I have a naive question that if someone could find the 
integral alternative of $$\sum_{\substack{2\le p\le n\\p\text{ is prime}}} f(p)$$ 
where f(p) is a non-decreasing monotonic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're looking for, and you haven't put any conditions on $f(p)$. But: if $f$ is continuous, then the sum can be written as a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Stieltjes_integral):
$$
\sum_{p\le n} f(p) = \int_1^n f(t) \,d\pi(t),
$$
where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes less than $x$. Then, if $f$ is actually differentiable, you can integrate by parts:
$$
\sum_{p\le n} f(p) = \pi(n)f(n) - \int_1^n \pi(t) f'(t) \,dt.
$$
(Most people haven't seen Riemann-Stieltjes integrals; the good news is you can just use the second formula without needing to really get the first formula. The second formlua can even be proven by hand, by dividing the integral up into the ranges between consecutive primes.)

One might subsequently be able to use facts about $\pi(x)$, for example, that $\pi(x)$ is very close to $x/\ln x$ when $x$ is large (that's the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !